# uploading photo via facebook API - pathname issues

Tags: php, image, facebook-graph-api

I'm currently having problems uploading an image via the facebook API - I am not returned any errors via the API and at this time I am thinking it is likely an issue with the file path I am passing in is incorrect.

The image is stored on our server after the user has used the app and I would then like to post it to facebook.

My code is below:

after running I receive no response from the API whereas if I for instance deliberately changed the oauth_token I'd receive an error (so I know the data is definitely posting)

I'm also printing the args array so I can see exactly what I'm posting:

here is the response.

If I navigate to the URL after the @ sign it is broken even if I remove the @C:\Domains and replace with www. I have tried passing in the URL that a user could actually navigate to if they were to know the filename

e.g https://www.example.co.uk/competition/fb/photos/collagetest.jpg

^ this is a valid link but when passing in the image is still not actually uploaded.

Any help would be massively appreciated!

```
Array ( [message] => Photo from ********[image] => @C:\Domains\******.co.uk\wwwroot\v2\competition\fb\photos\collagetest.jpg )

//upload photo
            $file= './photos/'.basename('collagetest.jpg');
            $args = array(
               'message' => 'Photo from friendbooth',
            );
            $args['image'] = '@' . realpath($file);
            $ch = curl_init();
            $url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/photos?access_token='.$_SESSION['oauth_token'];
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $args);
            $data = curl_exec($ch);
            print_r($args);
            //returns the photo id
            print_r(json_decode($data,true));

            ?>
            <img src="collagetest.jpg" />
            <?
```

Comment: drilled down a little more on the problem ---- as per below comment i checked if the file I was attempting to upload was readable. it is now but the photo still doesnt upload

I'm checking the return from facebook yet nothing is returned in $result

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $args);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    $result = @json_decode($data);

The url I am using is valid as I have checkedmanually

Answer (score 1):

> If I navigate to the URL after the @ sign it is broken

What do you mean by „broken”?

Is that file system path readable from within your PHP script? (Please *check*, don’t *guess*.)

> even if I remove the @C:\Domains and replace with www. I have tried passing in the URL

Giving a URL in this place is nonsense – a file system path is expected here. (Are you *aware* of the difference between the two?)

Comment: hi thanks for the response - I checked the $args['image'] path by using 

if(is_readable($args['image']))
    { 
     echo "got it";
    }
    else
    {
     echo "damn"; 
    }
unfortunately the path wasn't readable. 
do you know of any steps I would need to take to make it readable?

Answer (score 0):

turns out it was nothing to do with the file path in the end!

adding

```
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
```

completely resolved the issue! Hope this helps someone else in future. if posting to HTTPS urls try adding the above in if you aren't getting ANY response (error messages etc mean you are getting a response)